# Model binding MVC not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I will go straight to the problem: 
I have a problem passing data from javascript to a mvc controller and and get it to the provided model in a correct format. Here is the code(simplified):

sender.js

```
let data = JSON.stringify({id:1, username: 'name'});
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', host);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send(data);
```

controller:

```
public class About : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetData([FromBody]ModelDto data) {
        var incommingData = data;

        return View();
    }
}
```

ModelDto.cs:

```
public class ModelDto {
    public ModelDto() {}

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is: Apparently a model is binded, but with default values for the given type (0 and null for the given example). Kind regards.

Comment: can you use Jquery to send request?

Comment: The result with jquery is exactly the same. Thank you

Comment: Your current code has a typo (using name instead of UserName) .But it should work for the Id property value. Are you really sure the above code is not working ?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `FromBody` attribute?

Comment: I had typo on the post(fixed). Yes, I am sure, the parametter of the controller's method is getting filled with the defaults of the properties type.

Comment: Same result as with it.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it totally worked (the Id value was properly bound). when i fix typo, it binds the userName as well.

Comment: Do you have any model binders defined?

Comment: @mjwills: No I don't have any model binders ...

Comment: @Shyju: Here is not working.

Comment: Does it work if you submit the request from Postman? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: can you show all the http request headers and payload as shown in dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

you are sending property name 'name' but receiving 'username'.

property names should match

Comment: I have misspelled it here sorry. Let me fix it. Actually the properties have match.

Comment: I think correct casing is also needed i.e. Name not name.

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly created small solution and tried to reproduce your problem but everything works for me, so I guess the problem is not in the code that you pasted in your question.

Do you have some custom binders defined in your solution? Can you check how the request looks like for example in fiddler?